# Compare numbers in NSMutableArray with indexPath.row

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray that gets edited quite often as a TableView is edited.  What I want to do is run a check and see if rows in the TableView match up with any numbers in the NSMutableArray, and if they do, perform an action.  So, in the TableView code I have:

```
if([thearray containsObject:indexPath.row] {
   //perform action here
}
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to parameter of type 'id';
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I do this?

Comment: what do you even wanna do ^^

Comment: an NSArray can only contain ObjC Objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code...

```
if([thearray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]) {
   //perform action here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP is after; indexPath.row is likely supposed to correspond to an index of the array, not a member.

Comment: Your answer was perfect.  Just add the parentheses at the end of the if statement.  What I was doing is when a Row of the TableView is selected, it takes the number of the row, and adds it to an array that is stored in NSUserDefaults.  This way I have a number corresponding to every row that has been selected.  Then, I have this method to check which rows match the numbers in the array, so I can add a checkmark showing it has already been accessed.

Comment: @Fogmeister well, there you have it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do here is check if the current count of the array  is greater than indexPath.row the  (since in theory there will be no gaps in the indexes). The method you are currently calling takes an object and tells you if it is a member of the array. There is also `objectAtIndex:`, but that raises an exception if the integer you pass is out of bounds.

```
if(thearray.count > indexPath.row) {
  // array has at least indexPath.row + 1 items, so you can get objectAtIndex:indexPath.row
}
```